# Not able to show placeholder value again on a Select2 multiselect box after clearing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2, placeholder

I have been struggling with this for most of the day. I can't manage to show again the placeholder value defined on a multiple select box, enhanced with the Select2 plugin v3.5.2.

What is curious though is that it works in Select2 version 4.0. But I believe v4.0 is still in beta, and after a quick run of our site through Internet Explorer 11 after upgrading Select2 caused quite some issues. Also the bootstrap theme for Select2 v4.0 is still in beta. So all in all I would like to avoid upgrading at this stage!

I made a fiddle. As you can see, as soon as you press the clear button it is clearing the values but the placeholder message is not shown.

http://jsfiddle.net/joachimseminck/jb1rkc83/6/

Javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    $('#clear').click(function() {
        $('#select').select2("val", "");
    });

    $('#select').select2({
        placeholder: "Select an attribute"
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <select id="select" type="text" class="form-control" multiple=multiple>
        <option></option>
        <option value="Country1">Country1</option>
        <option value="Country2">Country2</option>
        <option value="Country3">Country3</option>
        <option value="Country4">Country4</option>
        <option value="Country5">Country5</option>
        <option value="Country6">Country6</option>
    </select>

    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" id="clear" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: Just a heads up, 4.0.0 was officially released on Sunday.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. I may look further into 4.0 as we are still in an early enough position to change but my first quick glance at it showed some issues with IE11 with these multi select boxes and placeholders. But perhaps I should investigate a little more!